# What does the point in the middle between two numbers mean?

Tags: terminology

> *[...] cells were removed to a cover glass and treated with plasma for 2 min, then returned to TS broth and centrifuged for 10 min. Cells were harvested and washed twice with PBS, then mixed with tryptic soy agar. The agar block was fixed with **2·5**% glutaraldehyde in **0·1** mol l−1 PBS. Samples were postfixed in 1% (w/v) OsO4 in **0·1** mol l−1 PBS for 2 h at room temperature, washed once with the same buffer, dehydrated in a graded ethanol series and embedded in low‐viscosity medium. Thin sections of the specimens were double‐stained with uranyl acetate and lead citrate...*

What does mean this bolded point? Is it a decimal separator, or has other scientific meaning?

If this is decimal point, why is vertically middle aligned?

*Source*: a recent [Korea researchers team article](http://www.surfxtechnologies.com/fileaway-directory/full/067.%20Sterilization%20effect%20of%20atmospheric%20plasma%20on%20Escherichia%20coli%20and%20Bacillus%20subtilis%20endospores.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

It's a decimal point.

**Longer answer**

A point in the 'middle' of the neighboring characters is called an [interpunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct), and was the standard in UK typography for marking a decimal at one point in time (possibly elsewhere as well). You're most likely to encounter it in older issues in UK and UK-inspired journals, and no doubt some have lagged behind the trends for reasons of tradition/stubbornness or whatever else and still use it.

Note that you will also encounter countries that use the *comma* as a decimal separator; [Wikipedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma) that includes most of mainland Europe and South America, for example.

Comment: I live in a country where the comma is decimal separator, this is common in Europe :) Thank you to clarifying that English Men habit )

Comment: This is even more strange cause encountered in a recent Korean article )) http://www.surfxtechnologies.com/fileaway-directory/full/067.%20Sterilization%20effect%20of%20atmospheric%20plasma%20on%20Escherichia%20coli%20and%20Bacillus%20subtilis%20endospores.pdf

Comment: ah, ok, the article was edited in an UK Journal ) https://sfamjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/